# how to use if statement with return to check if the function returns value when calling stored proc using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

`i need to check the value with return if getting some value when calling procedure in python`

```
` i need to check the value with return if getting some value when calling procedure in python`

def get_order_count(salesman_id, year):
    try:
        # create a connection to the Oracle Database
        with cx_Oracle.connect(cfg.username,
                            cfg.password,
                            cfg.dsn,
                            encoding=cfg.encoding) as connection:
            # create a new cursor
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                # create a new variable to hold the value of the
                # OUT parameter
                order_count = cursor.var(int)
                # call the stored procedure
                cursor.callproc('get_order_count',
                                [salesman_id, year, order_count])
                return order_count.getvalue()
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        print(error)

if order_count ==1
print ('succesesfull' )
else:
pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should test that the value you're about to return is valid before you call `return` to return it.  What is the check for a valid return value?  What do you want to return if that check fails?

Comment: you can do something like if(value==None) but you have to call proced first?  and if that check fails then return nothing

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what you want.  Can you update your question with more information?  Don't forget to call your own `get_order_count()` Python function.

Comment: There is one important code thing you need to do.  Your stored PL/SQL procedure _must_ assign a value to the OUT parameter in _all_ code paths (even in error code paths) because of a PL/SQL 'issue' when PL/SQL is invoked by Oracle's C libraries (such as used by cx_Oracle). See Oracle bug 22813401.  If you don't do this, then any Python checks on the return value cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: If you're just starting out with Python, update to the latest cx_Oracle version. It is now called [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`so inside a procedder there was if stament to check if run right then will return 1 if not 0 so we assing that to int value and then use it when calling procedure`

````
if order_count ==1:
print ('succesesfull' )
elif: order_count ==0:
print('faild')
else:
pass ```
````